# Tap notification when app is terminated not working, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I'm sending from a background task a local notification like this:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title"
content.subtitle = "Subtitle"
content.categoryIdentifier =  ...
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: ". . .", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

And i'm trying to manage if the user tap on it.

If the app is background or foreground I can handle this with my app delegate method (I need to show a new ViewController on tap)

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { // ... }
```

From: `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

But If I click on my notification with the app terminated nothing happend.

I'm trying to work on

```
if(launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil) { 
     Log.debug("LaunchOption remote notification tapped")
}
```

But I cant figure out how to handle the tap on my notification with the app terminated. All I need to ddo is show a newViewController

Comment: Welcome on Stack-overflow,
What do you mean by nothing happens? does the app open still, or literally nothing happens with the notification is touch (no dismissal, no change in UI nothing)?

Comment: the app load the launch screen but then it crash.

Comment: do you have anything in the logs of the device that might indicate the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to see the Debugger if the app is killed?

Comment: No but you can see the device log, by going to Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators. That will open a new window then select the device you are testing on and select "View Device Logs"

Comment: That is interesting but still cant find anything usefull from this